# ios NSPredicate search in array object

Tags: ios, search, nspredicate

How to search when i have this type of array 
here is one object of array

```
@interface Recipe : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* recipeName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* recipeId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* rcpDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* servingSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* totalCalories;
```

here i set recipename from  array data in tableview

```
Recipe* aRecipe = [recipeAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl_name = aRecipe.recipeName
```

BUt the problem is when i use NSPredicate is cant able to search here is my code please give me solution

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.recipeName= %@", searchText];
       // SELF.shipBuilder LIKE[cd] %@

        self.searchData = [recipeAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.searchData);
```

Comment: What's the value of `searchText`? What's the value you're trying to find? Are you looking for `CONTAINS[c]` instead?

Comment: i want to search recipeName but when i nslog my array it show <Recipe x04234> like this and search data is null

Comment: SPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.recipeName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];

Answer (score 0):

try using `%K`

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd]", recipeName, searchText];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to filter the results from the given array of *Recipe* objects

```
NSArray *recipeAry; //your data array

//create a search predicate to filter the array
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Recipe *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    return [evaluatedObject.recipeName hasPrefix:searchText];
}];

self.searchData = [recipeAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate]; //this is the filtered array you can use for the displaying UI with search results.
```